# Something between @include and @extend with sass

Tags: include, sass, extend

Is it possible to include a css rule in sass without duplicate the code?
With extend we are extending the code, but i dont want that eiter. I want include it, without duplicating code.

For **example**

**SCSS:**

```
.heading {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: my-cool-font;
}

.box {
    background: red;
    h1 {
        @extend .heading;
        color: white;
    }
}

.my-other-box {
    .heading {
        color: black;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
   <h1>My heading</h1>
</div>
<div class="my-other-box">
   <h1 class="heading">My heading</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading, .box h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: my-cool-font;
}
.box {
    background: red;
 }
.box h1 {
    color: white;
}

.my-other-box .heading,
.my-other-box .box h1,
.box .my-other-box h1 {
    color: black;
}
```

So the two last rules there are because its extending (I understand the benifits of it).
But if i want to both use classes, and extends i dont want it to extend, just include it. But i dont want it to duplicate the code.

I want:

**CSS**

```
.heading, .box h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: my-cool-font;
}
.box {
    background: red;
 }
.box h1 {
    color: white;
}

.my-other-box .heading {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an *extend class* (or use a class name that differs from one you're repeating elsewhere), you can get the output you're looking for:

```
%heading, .heading {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: my-cool-font;
}

.box {
    background: red;
    h1 {
        @extend %heading;
        color: white;
    }
}

.my-other-box {
    .heading {
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.box h1, .heading {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: my-cool-font;
}

.box {
  background: red;
}

.box h1 {
  color: white;
}

.my-other-box .heading {
  color: black;
}
```