# SASS: @extend the class outside of the scope

Tags: css, sass, extend

I have a scss selector like so：

```
.post-content {
    @for $i from 3 through 6 {
    h#{$i} { @extend h#{$i - 1};}
    }
}
```

such as `.post-content h4`, It will extend `h3`, But `h3` not just define in  `_pure.scss`, It also define in `.post-content`(previous loop). So we get this output(chaining extend):

```
/* line 141, ../sass/_pure.scss */
h2, .post-content h3, .post-content h4, .post-content h5, .post-content h6 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0.83em 0;
}

/* line 146, ../sass/_pure.scss */
h3, .post-content h4, .post-content h5, .post-content h6 {
  font-size: 1.17em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

/* line 151, ../sass/_pure.scss */
h4, .post-content h5, .post-content h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1.33em 0;
}

/* line 156, ../sass/_pure.scss */
h5, .post-content h6 {
  font-size: 0.83em;
  margin: 1.67em 0;
}

/* line 161, ../sass/_pure.scss */
h6 {
  font-size: 0.67em;
  margin: 2.33em 0;
}
```

But This is what I want:

```
h2, .post-content h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0.83em 0;
}

h3, .post-content h4 {
  font-size: 1.17em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

h4, .post-content h5 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1.33em 0;
}

h5, .post-content h6 {
  font-size: 0.83em;
  margin: 1.67em 0;
}
```

@extend-Only Selectors is not a solution:

```
@for $i from 3 through 6 { 
     %post-h#{$i} { @extend h#{$i - 1} ; } 
} 


.post-content {
    @for $i from 3 through 4 {
    h#{$i} { @extend %post-h#{$i} ; }
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
@mixin extendHeader($i) {
    @extend h#{$i};
}

.post-content {
    @for $i from 3 through 6 {
    h#{$i} { @include extendHeader($i - 1)}
    }
}
```

and this:

```
.post-content {
    $i: 6;
    @while $i > 2 {
    h#{$i} { @extend h#{$i - 1}; }
    $i: $i - 1;
    }
}
```

All Not working. Is there any way to get root reference of scss document?

Comment: Did you hear about [silent classes](http://csswizardry.com/2014/01/extending-silent-classes-in-sass/)?

Comment: Sorry, I cited an confusing example. I have updated my question . It's different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360482/something-between-include-and-extend-with-sass . So @extend-Only Selectors(%) is not a solution for this question.